# Writing Files not working (Windows 7)

Tags: python, file, file-io

I'm trying to output some of my data to an HTML file. 
Python has no problem creating a new file, but it seems to have problem with the write command. The program functions with no errors or warnings, but the filesize remains 0kb (empty).

I'm a bit of a newbie to python, so I'm hoping someone can point out my mistake.

Here is the code:

```
#OUTPUT
calcfile = open('calculation.html','w');

CALCOUT = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Quick Calculation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Estimate</h1>
        <table>
"""

#Some code which appends to CALCOUT -- long but it works perfectly via STDOUT. 

calcfile.write("%s" % CALCOUT);
#also tried calcfile.write(CALCOUT);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember to close the file after opening it. Or even better, use the `with` constuct, which closes files automatically as soon as the scope of the `with` block is exited.

```
with open('calculation.html','w') as calcfile:
    CALCOUT = """<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Quick Calculation</title>
            </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Estimate</h1>
            <table>
    """
    calcfile.write(CALCOUT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
calcfile.write(str(CALCOUT))
```

Also, there are no semicolons needed in Python.